# Groupby Pandas, gives not desired output

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a df with 3 colums,for illustration purpose I added a little snippet. I want to groupby the colum with the line PROJECTNAME`df.groupby('PROJECTNAME')`.
The output is not at all grouped,it's actually in the same format or the snippet. When checked for the types there are 2 int32 types, 1 object colum which is PROJECTNAME.
So my next guess was the PROJECTNAMES are not equal, but when boolen checked

```
df['PROJECTNAME'][14500] == df['PROJECTNAME'][14501]
```

the output is True.

| PROJECTNAME | Number | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ANI_CE-2022-1147 | 722333100 | 12213427 |
| ANI_CE-2022-1147 | 722333100 | 0 |
| ANI_CE-2022-1147 | 722333100 | 12213427 |

I am convinced that the variables are not the same and yet they seem to be the same. How can I further check what the groupby is hanging on to?

I hope I was able to express myself clearly, thank you in advance for any tip

Comment: Could you please add your code, and what aggregation function do you use?
groupby function alone doesn't do much. Have you read the documentation - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html ?

Comment: This is it, I didnt use any agg func.. The Code i use is the one i posted. df.groupby('PROJECTNAME'). Drop_dulicates will do the same for me if I just need the unique rows of the first 2 colums, but how would I transpose the last one ?

Comment: What is your desired output?